# Codes works in MIST and Remix but not in Parity & MEW

Tags: solidity

```
uint private mySecret;  

 function checkMySecret() constant returns (uint) {  
  if (owner == msg.sender){  
   return mySecret;  
  }  
 }
```

MIST and Remix works.
MEW and Parity does not work.